# Get first list item after ordered by name

Tags: ember.js

I have a template which uses `{{#each}}` to iterate over all of the items, and this list is ordered by name in the controller:

```
App.FoldersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortAscending: true,
    sortProperties: ['name']
});
```

I can access the `firstobject` in this list by making the following call:

```
this.modelFor('folders').get('firstObject');
```

But this returns the first item in the original list.

How can return the top item in the list `after` they have been ordered by the controller, e.g. the first item displayed by `{{#each}}`

Answer (score 1):

The `model` still has the items unsorted. The `controller` acts as a decorator on the `model` and sorts the items.

The property in the `controller` that is the decorated `model` is `arrangedContent`. So, you can say `arrangedContent.firstObject`

See the following jsbin for a working example - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mizutu/2/edit

Comment: In your example you access this within the template, but how can I access it from within the route? `this.controllerfor('folders').get('arrangedContent.firstObject')` doesn't work for me.

Comment: The following works (once you accessed the folders controller) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mizutu/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, closer but not quite right. In your example you have to transition to another route and then access the `controllerFor` which is too late. However, I want to be able to select the topmost item in the original route outlet. If I do that within the route in the `afterModel` hook, I get `arrangedContent = []` because it hadn't yet been processed.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your use case is, but you can always create a computed property on the controller like the following http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mizutu/5/edit